# Webpack and Loading custom scripts

Tags: angular, webpack, cryptojs

For the life of me I dont understand how webpack works. Please can somebody help me. Im going to explain with my situation but its actually more of a conceptual question of how to go about using webpack

So im working on an angular 2 project with a webpack starter. I have some js scripts that i got from AWS (my SDK for API-Gateway). Its about 10 js files. Currently i have those 10 files listed in my index.html, and that works great. Obviously this isnt actually great because that means 10 round trips to the server to collect them. So hence my journey into trying to get webpack to include them in a bundle starts

So what i tried to do was to import the files one by one in my main typescript file. The file where my app gets bootstrapped. Just like this for example:

```
import 'assets/aws-sdk/lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone.js';
import 'assets/aws-sdk/lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256.js';
import 'assets/aws-sdk/lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256.js';
...
```

Is this even remotely the right thing to do. This doesnt work. It complains about CryptoJS not being available in the files that require it. There are some crypto-js files in those that i bring in, and the files that use the variable 'CryptoJS' dont seem to see it.

I found in my webpack config a ProvidePlugin that seems to load jquery like this

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  /*CryptoJS: 'CryptoJS'*/
}),
```

So i added Crypto thinking it needs that. Doesnt work.

My question is this. The js files i need to use internally use a variable called CryptoJS to do things like this:

```
function hash(value) {
   return CryptoJS.SHA256(value);
}
```

That works fine including all the scripts in index.html, but how do i get my webpack app to understand what that means. How do i import and bundle these files, and how do i use a varable internal to those files like CryptoJS.

Answer (score 2):

Okay nevermind after hours of struggling i managed to figure it out. The import i was doing was wrong, to add the js files to the global space (equivalent of adding them to the index.html) is to import them like so

```
require('script!./assets/aws-sdk/lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone.js');
```

That script loader does the magic. Youll need that in your project as well can be installed from npm